# I'm trying to use coproject toolbar inside another view. Can't get it working

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm trying to use the coproject toolbar kind of view inside another view (ActiveItem). Coproject defines two content controls. But I want the toolbar to be nested in another view. Basically part of a CRUD form (view) so I can use it like a usercontrol in many other forms/views. I tried to include the Contentcontrol in my view. But the toolbar nevers shows up. It complains Project.Views.Form.tbar not found. How do I force it use the Toolbar view but use current viewmodel FormViewModel. Any help on customizing View locator would be very helpful.

Say there are two views: FormView & Toolbar (Toolbar should use the FormViewModel)

FormView.xaml: (I'm using toolbar view in this)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.FormView"
  <Grid>
      <Othercontrols>
      <ContentControl x:Name="Toolbar" cal:View.Model="{Binding}" cal:View.Context="tbar" />
      <OtherControls>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Toolbar.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.Toolbar">
  <Border>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Width="135">
       <local:ImageButton x:Name="Add" ImageName="Pen" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Add" />
       <local:ImageButton x:Name="Edit" ImageName="Pen" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Edit" />
       <local:ImageButton x:Name="Save" ImageName="Save" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Save"  />
       <local:ImageButton x:Name="Delete" ImageName="Close" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Delete" />
       <local:ImageButton x:Name="Cancel" ImageName="Undo" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Cancel"  />
   </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

As I said earlier, the Toolbar should use the parent view model where it is used. In above case, it should use FormViewModel. The FormViewModel will have the methods "Add", "Edit" and etc.

Please let me know how to get this working? 
Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

What about to use cal:View.Model="{Binding Parent}"? Provided that the child ViewModel has this property filled with proper parent ViewModel.